# I want to build a simple checkout page using the Stripe Prebuilt Checkout Page in a symfony application

Tags: stripe-payments

Error: Not a valid URL

I don't think I've missed anything from the docs. Any idea what's going wrong? Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.st)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbrmG.png)ack.imgur.com/1wux3.png

Comment: From the images, it looks like one specific image URL is not valid (whatever you passed into `line_items[1][price_data][product_data][images][0]`). You should log that out and verify you're actually passing in a valid URL

Comment: hello yes indeed you are right thank you very much for your help , i changed the URL ans it works

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.